# Why Playframework database configuration error in application.conf

Tags: postgresql, configuration, playframework, slick

I have have correct PostgreSQL installed and I can use this by other framework such as Spring. When I tried write some code for Play 2.1 that should use postgresql 9.4.1. I'm also using Slick 3.0.

I have following in the application.conf

db.default.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"

db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql:mydb"

db.default.user=myuser

db.default.password=mypass

When I start application it give error:-

Missing configuration [db.ansiDump.driver]

I added

db.ansiDump.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"

db.ansiDump.url="jdbc:postgresql:mydb"

Then I get error:-

Missing configuration [db.unicodeDump.driver]

I added

db.unicodeDump.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"

db.unicodeDump.url="jdbc:postgresql:mydb"

Then I get error:-

Missing configuration [db.dumpPaths.driver]

So again I added:-

db.dumpPaths.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"

db.dumpPaths.url="jdbc:postgresql:mydb"

After all these sequence of driver and url, It worked. I am sure, I am doing something wrong to configure drive o url.

Please tell me what is wrong and how it should be done.

## Updated infromation:-

Additional information.

Sorry I can't keep correct format for the whole application.conf file content. So I uploaded it in Google Drive. Please check the link [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B08T2-rP3WGAQUVmRndnYk9pRVE/view?usp=sharing)

To reproduce the error I had to comment line number 45 #db.ansiDump.driver="org.postgresql.Driver"

After comment I get this exception:-

Configuration error
Missing configuration [db.ansiDump.driver]
In /Users/ma/work/app/conf/application.conf:45

Answer (score 0):

I think the url should be

```
db.default.url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbName"
```

Comment: @masiboo post your full `application.conf` and `exception` in your question and dont forget to format it.

Comment: please check the link in Updated information  for complete application.conf or https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B08T2-rP3WGAQUVmRndnYk9pRVE/view?usp=sharing